# Zeta function of the hypersurface of some homogeneous polynomial

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, analytic-functions, zeta-functions

Let $f(y)\in \Bbb Z_p[y_0,y_1,....,y_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial. Let $N_s$ be the number of zeros of $f$ in $\Bbb P^n(F_{p^s})$. Here, $\Bbb P^n(F_{p^s})$ denotes the $n$-th projective space defined over the finite field with $p^s$ elements.

My question is how does the series $\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}\frac{N_su^s}{s}$ define an analytic function on the disc $\{u\in \Bbb C:|u|<q^{-n}\}$.

Comment: did you mean $|u|<p^{1-n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the radius of convergence for your power series by applying the root test which says that the radius of convergence is

$$ r=1/(\limsup_{s\to \infty} \sqrt[s]{N_s/s})$$

You could use the estimate that $N_s \le \#\mathbf P^n(\mathbf F_{p^s}) \le (n+1) (p^s)^n$.

Comment: Indeed the radius of convergence stays $p^{-n}$ when counting the number of roots in  $\Bbb{A^{n+1}(F_{p^s})}$ (look at $f(t,X) =\sum_{n=0}^d c_n(X) t^n \in \Bbb{F}_p[t,X], c_d(X)^{d-1} f(t/c_d(X),X) \in \Bbb{F}_p[t,X]_{monic}$) so that when counting the number of roots in  $\Bbb{P^n(F_{p^s})}$ the radius of convergence is $p^{1-n}$